# Proof: Zero is less than one

Tags: field-theory, axioms

How can one show/prove that $0<1$?

$1$ is not actually defined to be greater than zero, but I think it can be proven. I already know that the real numbers are an ordered field and I am familiar with the field axioms and the definition of a total ordering. However I do not know how to start such a proof.

Any kind of help or advice will be really appreciated.

Comment: What is the definition you are using for "<" ?  There are different equivalent definitions. In some of the $0< 1$  is actually part of the definition.

Answer (score 7):

$1 = 1^2$ and $x^2>0$ if $x\ne 0$.

For the last claim, the main point is that by definition of *positive* $x,y>0$ implies $xy>0$. This is used as follows:

If $x>0$ then $x^2 = x \cdot x > 0$.

If $x<0$ then $-x > 0 $ and so $x^2=(-x)^2 > 0$.

In turn, this follows from $(-x)y=-(xy)$, which follows from distributivity:
$0 = (-x + x)y = (-x)y+(xy)$.

Comment: For the details, see for instance Chapter 1 of Spivak's *Calculus*.

Comment: Nice. However, as you pointed out, your proof relies on the property "if $x,y>0$ then $x.y>0$".  Since @Fullbright did not specify which definition of $<$ is being used,  the property you used may not be "evident". In fact, it may be harder to prove than $0<1$.

Comment: @Ramiro, that's usually in the definition of [ordered field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field#Definitions).

Comment: I know. But, for instance, there are equivalent variants of the definition where $0<1$ is part of the definition and  the property "if $x,y>0$ then $x.y>0$" is deduced using that $0<1$.

Answer (score 2):

I'll add some details/more information to @lhf answer:

In an ordered field $K$, there is a distinguished subset $P$ such that:

(i) $\{ P,\{0\},-P\}$ is a *partition* of $K$,

(ii) $\forall x,y\in P$, $\; x+y\in P\;$ and $\;xy\in P$.

In particular, as $\;1=1\cdot 1=(-1)\cdot(-1)$, we see $1\in P$.

We then define a *strict order* relation on $K$ by setting $x>y$ if $x-y\in P$. In particular, $\;x\in P\iff x>0$.

Comment: The other approach to defining ordered fields is to say that there is total order that is compatible with addition and with multiplication by positive elements, where positive means > 0.

Comment: They're equivalent, of course, but I personally prefer this one, as I find it more natural.