# Why is 1 greater than 0? Show the proof.

Tags: proof-writing, definition, axioms

I would like to prove that 1 > 0. And I need to use axioms, could somebody help me?
Thanks'

Comment: A proof depends on which axioms you need to use. You could take $1 > 0$ as an axiom and declare victory but that probably isn't what is required.

Comment: well, so 1 > 0 is not an axiom and i have to prove it using axioms.. and i dont have idea how to prove it..

Comment: well, we use basic axioms...

Comment: This really is tricky without knowing which axioms you would be using - that would likely be in a reference text that you are using.  If you look at the Peano Axioms ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Inequalities ), you might find something that helps.

Comment: Questions like this are best asked of the instructor of the course.  He knows what axioms are used in that course.  We do not.  Different treatments may start with different axioms.  But (we hope) they all arrive at the same place eventually.

Answer (score 5):

The usual proof relies on $a^2> 0$ for any nonzero real number $a$. If you can prove that as a lemma from the basic axioms, and you note that 1 is the multiplicative identity, you will be done.

Comment: Thanks. I found something like that:

Comment: 6
down vote
1=121=12 and x2>0x2>0 if x≠0x≠0.

For the last claim, the main point is that by definition of positive x,y>0x,y>0 implies xy>0xy>0. This is used as follows:

If x>0x>0 then x2=x⋅x>0x2=x⋅x>0.

If x<0x<0 then −x>0−x>0 and so x2=(−x)2>0x2=(−x)2>0.

In turn, this follows from (−x)y=−(xy)(−x)y=−(xy), which follows from distributivity: 0=(−x+x)y=(−x)y+(xy)0=(−x+x)y=(−x)y+(xy).

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1458288/proof-zero-is-less-than-one this :D

Answer (score 3):

It does very much depends on what "basic axioms" you use.  Believe it or not not all mathematicians use the same.  YOu should list which ones you have.

From an algebra perspective, we can use the ordered field axioms.

There's a lot of things to prove.

Intermediate and nescessary things to prove but our big goal is:

a) For all $a\ne 0$ we know $a^2 > 0$.

Then we are done, as $1 = (1)^2 > 0$.

To prove a) we usually have an axioms $a > b; and x > 0$ then $ax > bx$.  We also have if $a > b$ then $a + x > b+x$ for all x$.

From there we can prove $x > 0 \iff 0 > -x$ by noting $x > 0 \implies x-x > 0 -x$ so $0 > -x$.

We need to prove tedious little things such as $(-x)(y) = x(-y) = -xy$ but using the axiom $a(b+c) = ab + bc$ and that for all $a$ there is a unique $-a$ so that $a+(-a) = 0$.  Then we need to prove $(-x)(-y) = xy$.

This is all to prove that if $a > b$ and $x < 0$ then $ax < ab$ (because $x < 0 \implies -x > 0 \implies a(-x) > b(-x) \implies -ax > -bx \implies -ax +ax + bx > -bx +ax +bx \implies $bx > ax$).

So with all that in mind we can prove: If $x > 0$ then $x^2 =x*x > 0*x = 0$.  And if $x < 0$ then $x*x > 0*x$ so $x^2 > 0$.  So as long as $x \ne 0$ we have $x^2 > 0$!

So $1 = 1^2 > 0$!

Answer (score 1):

It follows directly from Peano's axioms.

You might want to refer to the different axioms you use.

Comment: well, i dont have any expierence with that, so..

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda tricky to answer without knowing the context in which you are trying to prove it in. If you are talking strictly purely, as in I have a number 0 and the number 1 (as we all know them), then the proof is from the Peano axioms:

Axiom 1: 0 is in $\mathbb{N}$

Axiom 2: If x is in $\mathbb{N}$ then x+1 is in $\mathbb{N}$

Axiom 3: Any subset of $\mathbb{N}$ that satisifies the above actually coincides with $\mathbb{N}$.

Axiom 4: If x in $\mathbb{N}$ then x+1 $\neq$ 0

Axiom 5: If x+1=y+1 then x=y.

These are basic axioms of the natural numbers, the assertion comes from the fact that since 1 is in $\mathbb{N}$, and by axiom 4 no successor of 1 is 0, 1 must be a successor of 0 and hence bigger than. (This is hand wavey, a sucessor of x is a number which comes after x, i.e x'=x+1, x''=(x+1)+1... and a true proof would go into depths about orderings and the word 'bigger')

tl;dr By axioms, any natural number can be obtained by starting with 0 and adding 1 to it a certain amount of times so 1 can't be less than 0 and it certainly isn't equal, ergo it is greater than.

I've a casual interest in set theory which is why my mind went this way, however for a thorough proof you'd have to start from the bottom and define everything and prove existence of things.

Comment: We have to prove that in R:

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are using the axioms for an ordered field, which is a field with a linear order that interacts with the field's arithmetic according to :

Rule 1. If $a<b$ then $a+c<b+c.$

Rule 2. If $a<b$ and $0<c$ then $ac<bc.$

Now it is axiom of fields that the additive identity $0$ is not equal to the multiplicative identity $1.$ So in an ordered field we must have $0<1$ or $1<0$ . To show that the case $1<0$ is untenable, we have :$$1<0\implies 0<-1$$ because $0=1+(-1)<0+(-1)=-1$ by Rule 1 with $a=1, b=0, c=-1.$ But then, using Rule 2, with $a=1, b=0, c=-1$ we  have  $$1<0 \implies (1<0 \text { and } 0<-1)\implies -1=1(-1)<0(-1)=0\implies  -1<0.$$ So $1<0$ implies both $0<-1$ and $-1<0 , $ which is untenable for a linear order $<.$